# expected , or ; before if

Tags: c, gcc

I made a stupid mistake (forgot semicolon, too much Python lately), but got an interesting error message from gcc: "expected ',' or ';' before 'if'".

I know those error messages provide just an "upper bound" for possible source code, but I'd like to know if there is any construct in C such that "if" token really comes after ',' and not after ';'.

Comment: And that's how you switched to clang.

Comment: @H2CO3 For a mere cryptic error message? If you are looking for a real reason to flee from GCC, I'd go read its source code, or coding standard.

Comment: @Lundin The coding standard is not related to GCC - it's related to GNU in general. Also, you doesn't seem to have gotten my point - it's not merely a cryptic error message, clang produces way more meaningful and visually better warnings in general. (Sidenote: I'm still all for GCC.)

Comment: @H2CO3 GCC uses the GNU coding standard and then [some additional rules](http://gcc.gnu.org/codingconventions.html). They are both equally lame, containing a lot of formatting rules, but not any programming rules worth mentioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After isn't necessarily *immediately after*.  The error message is more: 'I've just hit an 'if' construct.  At this point I was expecting either an end to the (previous) statement, or the next item in the list.  One of those things must be before this 'if', so I'm letting you know'

Comment: My fault, gcc is right. The previous line was a declaration of a local variable (local to a block, with an initializer), and it really is a "list". Thank you. (I thought the previous line was an assignment statement, and ',' just didn't apply there.)

Comment: Was just about to ask what you were doing in that line.  cool

Comment: This is probably true, but the answer to the actual question that was asked is "No", as explained by Nolwenn.

Comment: As I stressed, strictly speaking he's only correct if he inserts 'immediately' before preceded.

Answer (score 5):

> I'd like to know if there is any construct in C such that "if" token really comes after ',' and not after ';'.

According to the [C BNF grammar](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf), an `if` is *always* at the beginning of a statement. So no, it can't be preceded by a `,`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no situation where a comma can appear before an `if` statement. So this must be a compiler typo/bug in gcc.

I would guess that the gcc parser is looking for a *[sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575350/sequence-points-in-c)* before an if statement. There is a sequence point at a semicolon, but there is also one where to comma operator is used inside an expression. So it would seem that the error printing for errors in whole statements and expressions is the same, somehow.

Comment: No, that's not it. Sequence points are also at '&&', for example, and it isn't mentioned.

Comment: @user1875565 It is as good as any mind reading guess. Anyway, the error text is not correct, as far as the C standard is concerned.