# An example about operator precedences

Tags: c, operator-precedence

As far as I'm aware of, unary operators have prior precedence over `||` and `&&`. In the following code, I'd expect an output where all outputs are equal to 1. Yes, there is a short-circuit but shouldn't those pre-increments calculated before `||` and `&&`? How these precedences work here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    a = b = c == 1;
    c = ++a || ++b && ++c;    // short-circuit here
    printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
}

Output:
a=1 b=0 c=1
```

Comment: Did you really mean `a = b = c == 1;`?

Comment: You're mixing up "precedence" with "order of evaluation". "precedence" tells us that it means `(++a) || ((++b) && (++c))`, and not for example `++( (a || (++b)) && ++c)`  , but says nothing more specific about which order those operations are executed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Actually the second operand **must not** be evaluated if the result is determined by the first operand already. It is not just left to the compiler.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't say that. It is determined by the value of the operands, and the nature of the operator.

Comment: Note that if `a` starts off as `-1`  (so that `++c` gets evaluated), that line causes undefined behaviour as there are no sequence points between `++c` and `c =`  (the sequence points from the || && are strictly before `++c`). To avoid this issue you could use a different variable for the result.  Theoretically a compiler could notice this and then assume `a != -1`

Comment: @juanchopanza: Isn't "do not have to" weaker than `must not`? Anyway, the second operand must be evaluated if required.

Comment: @erip Yes, `a` and `b` assigned like that.

Comment: `a = b = c == 1;` is a slightly odd line (this actually has no effect)

Comment: @Olaf must not isn't accurate, because the operands may be evaluated. Depending on their value and the nature of the operator. Must not suggests they are never evaluated.

Comment: @juanchopanza the way you worded your comment, it looks like you are suggesting that even if the short-circuiting occurs, the later operands might be evaluated anyway

Comment: @juanchopanza: I think I wrote that very clear: " ... must not be evaluated **if** ... "

Comment: @M.M: Thanks, that's what I mean.

Comment: @M.M Fine, I'll remove it. I got confused by OP claiming they understand short circuit, but obviously that isn't the case.

Comment: @erip Right, I was mixing them. So can we conclude that "Precedence makes those term grouped but doesn't guarantee that they will be evaluated before all others."?

Comment: @erip you just restated the misconception.  Precedence determines the grouping of terms, but not what happens first (other than the minimum required by that particular grouping)

Comment: Trying `c = ++b && ++c || ++a;` instead of `c = ++a || ++b && ++c;` makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `||` is short-circuiting and the lowest precedence operator explains the result.  Because `++` is the higher precedence than `&&` and `&&` is higher precedence than `||`, the expression tree for `++a || ++b && ++c` is:

```
       ||   -- left:   ++a
            -- right:  &&   --left:  ++b
                            --right: ++c
```

So, to evaluate the expression, C first considers the rules for evaluating `||`, given by 6.5.14 in the C11 standard.  Specifically:

> 6.5.14.4:  Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

The fact that `||` is short-circuiting means that it evaluates its left operand first and only evaluates its right operand if the left is zero.  So to evaluate the expression `++a || ++b && ++c`, C requires the following:

1. Evaluate `++a` (`a` is incremented by one and the expression is equal to its incremented value).  If it is non-zero, then `||` expression is equal to `1` *and the right side is never evaluated.*
2. Otherwise, evaluate `++b` and `++c`, in left-to-right order. If `++b` is zero, then `++c` is never evaluated.  If both are non-zero, then the expression is equal to `1`.

Because `++a` evaluates to 1, the right side of the `||` is never evaluated.  This is why you have `a==1`, `b==0`, and `c==1`.

There's one additional problem with the statement `c = ++a || ++b && ++c`, which is that there's a potential for the statement to invoke undefined behavior.  If `++a` is false and `++b` is true, then `++c` has to be evaluated.  However, there is no sequence point between `c = ...` and `++c`.  Since the expressions both modify `c` with no sequence point in between, the behavior is undefined.  For a further explanation of this see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575375/1430833

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference. That's why I'm choosing this as the answer.

Comment: You've not mentioned that the expression as a whole has the potential for undefined behaviour because `c = … && ++c` modifies and uses `c` between sequence points (the sequence point after the LHS of `&&` is evaluated and the end of statement).  GCC points that out (`warning: operation on ‘c’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`).  In this case, because of the values involved, it is OK; the `c++` is never executed and `c` acquires the value `1` from the fact that the expression as a whole evaluates to `1` (true) because `++a` is non-zero.

Comment: You also say "evaluate `++b` and `++c`, in no guaranteed order", but the order of evaluation is guaranteed — the `&&` and `||` operators guarantee that their LHS is fully evaluated before the RHS is evaluated, including side-effects, because there is a full sequence point between evaluation of the LHS and the evaluation of the RHS.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right about `&&`.  That was careless of me.  I thought it would cloud the issue to point out that there's a sequence point issue with `++c` since that will never arise in the OP's code, but that's certainly true.

Comment: If `++a` and `++b` are both false, will `++c` be evaluated? I think `++b && ++c` would be directly evaluated to `false`.

Comment: @Motun, you're absolutely right.  I was short on time when I made that edit, and `++c` is only evaluated when `++a` is false and `++b` is true.  I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Operator precedence* doesn't have any relation with *order of evaluation*. Higher precedence means that grouping of operands to that operator is done first.

In the statement

```
c = ++a || ++b && ++c;
```

the grouping/binding of the operands of `++` will be done first and then that of `&&` and `||` respectively. To show this I am adding parenthesis to the expression

- `++` has higher precedence so bind operand to it first

  ```
  c = (++a) || (++b) && (++c);
  ```
- `&&` has higher precedence than `||`

  ```
  c = (++a) || ((++b) && (++c));
  ```
- `||` has higher precedence than `=`

  ```
  c = ((++a) || ((++b) && (++c)));
  ```
- `=` has least precedence of all

  ```
  (c = ((++a) || ((++b) && (++c))));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) with [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). Here's an outline of what happens. In the comments, my use of `=` is that of identity - much like the mathematical equals sign.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // all variables are assigned the value 0
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

    // a and b are equal to the evaluation of `c == 1`, which is false. a and b are 0
    a = b = c == 1;

    /* 
       && has higher precedence than ||, so ++b and ++c are "grouped": ++a || (++b && ++c)
       ++a is evaluated, a = 0+1 = 1. 1 is true, short circuit the second grouping. 
       c = a = 1.
    */
    c = ++a || ++b && ++c;    // short-circuit here

    // a = c = 1, b = 0
    printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
}
```