# Inner workings of call by reference

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int *num1, int *num2) {
    *num1 = 50; 
    ++*num2++;
}

int main() {
    int num1 = 1; int num2 = 2;
    char bye[] = "Bye World!";
    printf("Hello World!\n%s\n", &bye);
    printf("num1: %d, num2: %d\n", num1, num2);
    change(&num1, &num2);
    printf("num1: %d, num2: %d\n", num1, num2);
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Looking at the following code, why is the output:

```
Hello World! Bye world!
num1: 1, num2: 2
num1: 50, num2: 3
```

instead of

```
Hello World! Bye world!
num1: 1, num2: 2
num1: 50, num2: 4
```

Under `change()`, shouldn't `num2` still be incremented by one after the
pre-increment? I imagine this is what happens in memory:

- num2 = 2 (before call to change())
- num2 = 3 (the pre-increment)
- num2 = 3 (value returned before the post-increment)
- num2 = 4 (the post-increment)

Comment: post-increment to pointer.

Comment: `++*num2++` == `++*(num2++)`

Comment: `++*num2++` == ++*num2, num2++. your want `++*num2, (*num2)++.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under `change()` shouldn't `num2` still be incremented by one after the pre-increment?

No, it shouldn't. There are two reasons for it:

- **Pre-increment increments the value; post-increment increments the pointer** — in `++*num2++` the first `++` applies to whatever is pointed to by `num2`, but the second one applies to `num2` itself due to [*precedence rules*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence): post-increment have higher precedence than pre-increment and dereference.
- **If you set precedence by parentheses, one expression cannot modify the same value twice** — this is a rule explained in [Q&A on sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3575350/335858).

Answer (score 0):

```
++*num2++;
```

means the same as:

```
++(*(num2++));
```

i.e. it increments `*num2` and `num2` once each. It does not increment `*num2` twice.