# Is the order of evaluation defined for a[i++] = i;?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

as title, in C++, is the evaluation order defined for

```
a[i++] = i;
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot use a single variable more than once in a full expression if at any point it's changed.

Comment: Not totally true, you have to take into account  [sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575350/sequence-points-in-c), but in this case, yes, it's undefined behavior

Comment: This will change shortly [with C++17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17) though.

Comment: Please extend your answer concerning C++17 features.

Comment: @DawidPi I cannot add anything that would not be in Quentin's linked question already in a better format.