# pointers in the function C

Tags: c, pointers

This piece of code works fine. But I'm wondering if it can be done in a more efficient way?

More specifically this part  `*(s1 + i)` if it possible to force it to sequence through entire array character by character via pointer  for example `*s1++`.
My task to do this function compareStrings without index array [].

```
 int  compareStrings(const char  *s1, const char  *s2)
{
    int i = 0, answer;
    //  i - to sequence through array of characters
    // pointer to character string1 and character string2
    while (*(s1 + i) == *s2 + i && *(s1 + i) != '\0'&& *(s2 + i) != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    if ( *(s1 + i) < *(s2 + i) )
        answer = -1;               /* s1 < s2  */
    else if ( *(s1 + i) == *(s2 + i) )
            answer = 0;                 /* s1 == s2 */
        else
            answer = 1;                 /* s1 > s2  */

        return answer;
```

But I want to change it to `s1++` and `s2++` insted of `*(s1 + i)` and `*(s2 + i)`. I've tried to implement this idea with pining an extra pointer to the beginning but I've failed. Here the code -->

```
int  compareStrings(const char  *s1, const char  *s2)
{
    int answer;
    char **i = s1, **j = s2;
    // i and j - to sequence through array of characters
    while (*(i++) == *(j++) && *(i++) != '\0'&& *(j++) != '\0');

    if (*i < *j)
        answer = -1;               /* s1 < s2  */
    else if (*i == *j)
        answer = 0;                 /* s1 == s2 */
    else
        answer = 1;                 /* s1 > s2  */

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I think it's better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: while (*(s1 + i) == *(s2 + i) && *(s1 + i) != '\0'&& *(s2 + i) != '\0')

Comment: if you do `s1++` you will loose the beginning of the data. Pin an extra pointer to the beginning.

Comment: For sake of readability you really should write `s1[1]` instead of `*(s1 + 1)`.

Comment: It's not working at least because of `*s1++ == *s1++`

Comment: It's my task to do this function without index array [] @Michael Walz!

Comment: I've add extra pointer to the begining and it's not working char **i = s1, **j = s2;

 while (*(i++) == *(j++) && *(i++) != '\0'&& *(j++) != '\0');    @Tony Tannous

Comment: @Yellowfun why this strange requirement ? Is it from your teacher ? `*(x + y)` is strictly equivalent to `x[y]`, it will generate exactly the same code once compiled. The __only__ difference is readability.

Comment: Can I represent this code with idea 's1++'?  @Michael Walz

Comment: @Yellowfun no, but in the first part of your code there is no `++` anyway. And in the second part there is no `*(x + y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compare C-strings, all you need is

```
int str_cmp(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    while (*s1 != 0 && *s2 != 0 && *s1 == *s2)
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }

    if (*s1 == *s2)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return *s1 < *s2 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The latter code isn't working, because you increment `s1` twice:

```
*s1++ == *s1++
```

This will:

1. Get the value of `s1`
2. Dereferene it
3. Increment by 1
4. Then on the right side, do the same again
5. And only then compare it.

You essentially are doing this:

```
*(s1) == *(s1+1)
```

I think that should actually be:

```
*s1++ == *s2++
```

Comment: Are you sure about `*(s1+1) == *(s1+2)` ? It would be `*(s1) == *(s1+1)` because postfix increment returns old value.

Comment: Good catch. Corrected that!

Comment: I'm not sure, but for me, `*s1++ == *s1++` has **_undefined behavior_**, because `==` isn't a [sequence point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575350/sequence-points-in-c), so, you don't know which `s1++` (left or right) are evaluated first. so you can absolutely not say that is equivalent to ` *(s1) == *(s1+1)`, because it can also be `*(s1+1) == *(s1)` or something else (undefined behavior)