# Return statement with comma

Tags: c, linux, return, cat

This is the popular bash command `cat` written in C.

I have no idea what this line does:

```
if (argc==1) return cat(stdin), 0;
```

I've never seen anything like it before. Here's the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void cat(FILE *f)
{
        int     c;

        while (EOF != (c = getc(f)))
        {
                if (EOF == putchar(c))
                {
                        perror("cat");
                        return;
                }
        }
        if (ferror(f))
        {
                perror("cat");
                return;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if (argc==1) return cat(stdin), 0;
        for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
        {
                if (!strcmp("-", argv[i]))
                {
                        cat(stdin);
                        continue;
                }
                FILE *f = fopen(argv[i], "r");
                if (!f)
                {
                        perror("cat");
                        continue;
                }
                cat(f);
                fclose(f);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

What does the line `if (argc==1) return cat(stdin), 0;` do?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
cat(stdin), 0
```

is a [comma expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator). This kind of expression evaluates all the operands (separated by commas) in order from left to right, with an implicit [sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575350/sequence-points-in-c) at each comma, and finally returns the value of the rightmost operand (in this case `0`).

As an example, here:

```
int x = (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

the variable `x` assumes the value `4`. There are cases in which the expression needs to be parenthesized to avoid ambiguity (e.g. like I just did above) and cases in which it is not needed (e.g. after `return`).

All in all, there are very few cases in which a comma expression makes sense, and this certainly isn't one of them. The code you show could be rewritten as:

```
if (argc == 1) {
    cat(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `return cat(stdin), 0;` simply executes `cat(stdin)` before returning `0`. It's a silly "trick" to make the code fit in one line.