# I don't understand how the final values of 2 variables are calculated after an addition of a pre-increment and post-increment

Tags: c, operator-precedence, post-increment, pre-increment, associativity

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    j = i++ + ++i;
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
return 0;
}
```

After compilation and run, the output is i = 2 and j = 2

I don't understand how the final values of i and j are calculated

I just want to understand about precedence and associativity in this specific example of code

Comment: Please see [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior) and see [sequence points in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575350/sequence-points-in-c). The certain outcome is that `i == 2` although exactly *when* it becomes `2` is undefined.

Comment: The short answer is "there is no explanation; the code has undefined behaviour".  And that means any result is acceptable.  The relevant restriction is in the C11 standard a [§6.5 Expressions ¶2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p2): _If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined._. It's a bit inscrutable, but 'unsequenced' has a specific meaning and the `i++` and `++i` operations are unsequenced.

Comment: See [§5.1.2.3 Program execution ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p3) for the definition of 'sequenced before' (and 'sequenced after') and 'unsequenced' (and 'indeterminately sequenced').

Comment: And see [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/15168) for a discussion of what undefined behaviour means.