# Is i = 0, ++i defined?

Tags: c++, c

I recently learned about the `,` operator and the fact that it introduces a *sequence point*.

I also learned that the following code led to undefined behavior:

```
i = ++i;
```

Because `i` was modified twice between two sequence points.

But what about the following codes ?

```
i = 0, ++i;
i = (0, ++i);
```

While I know the rules, I can't get to a conclusion. So is it defined behavior or not ?

**edit:** Just as @paxdiablo mentions, *defined or not*, this is really a **bad practice** which should be avoided. This question is asked solely for educational purposes and better understanding of the "rules".

Comment: @paxdiablo: Do you really think I'd use such a useless statement in real code ?! It's only about understanding the rules better. Nothing more.

Comment: @ereOn it's good to learn the rules, that's true. But after a while experience usually leads coders to avoid any constructs that are not well-defined and in common use across all platforms.

Comment: @PP: Fair enough. I probably made it sound like I was going to use it in my own code but actually, I would be one of the first to complain if there was crappy code like this in our codebase. It was just a question that came to me this morning and which I couldn't get rid of. :)

Comment: @paxdiablo: In Maths you never try divide by zero. Half of Analysis is based around the behaviour of just that though, since it helps you understand how numbers work better. It's a good thing to question why you shouldn't do things, and what happens when you do, you learn about a lot more than just that single behaviour.

Comment: @AaronM: Analyzing consequences is one thing, tossing some Is, plusses, and punctuation before a question mark is another.  I'd swear I've seen ~15 variations on this topic by now, with very little or no analysis from the OP each time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes.  `=` has higher precedence than `,`, so this expression is equivalent to `(i = 0), ++i`.  `,` is a sequence point, so it's guaranteed that the `++i` occurs after the assignment.

I'm not sure whether `i = (0, ++i)` is defined though.  My guess would be no; there's no sequence point between the increment and the assignment.

Comment: I came up to the same intuition but the fact I can't be sure bothers me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @ereOn: My intuition is that because the standard doesn't guarantee it, it's undefined.

Comment: Because of the parentheses, the increment will be evaluated before the assignment, so I also think it will be undefined.

Comment: @codymanix: If it is guaranteed to be evaluated **before** the assignement, doesn't it then become **defined** ?

Comment: Sequence points are always between evaluations, and sequence the side effects caused by them. There is a sequence point between "0" and "++i". But not between the assignment and the increment, as @Oli pointed out. For examples like `i = (0, ++i, 0)`, I don't think the C++03 Standard is clear about. I think you could make a point for it to be defined, but I will never rely on it: To me it is just undefined aswell.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Makes sense, indeed.

Comment: ereOn: a guarantee that an uninitialized value is incremented and then assigned to another variable sounds not very defined. The whole thing about undefined statements in C will always remain a mystery to me. Why is not compiler able to tell you that statement is undefined?

Comment: @codymanix: Parentheses force operator binding, they don't provide a sequence point.

Comment: I believe that in this case, `i = (0, ++i);` is semantically equivalent to `i = ++i;` which, as has been pointed out earlier, is undefined.

Comment: @oli: But in this case the parentheses groups the sequence point, which is what matters.

Comment: @codymanix: Just in the same way that the parentheses don't make `i = (++i)` defined.

Answer (score 7):

```
i = 0, ++i;
```

As the other answer pointed out it is not Undefined Behaviour.

```
i = (0, ++i);
```

The behaviour is undefined in this case because there is no sequence point between `++i` and assignment to i.

```
i = (0, ++i, 0)
```

The behaviour is well defined<sup>1</sup> in C++03, IMHO.

<sub><sup>1</sup> See [extended discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895922/sequence-points-and-partial-order) for a similar expression.</sub>