# c, bitwise, logic expression

Tags: c

```
int x = 0;
x^=x || x++ || ++x;
```

and the answer for x at last is 3.
How to analysis this expression?
little confused about this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895922/sequence-points-and-partial-order (question assumes knowledge of sequence points) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept (see accepted answer). Not *exact* duplicates, but this UB is "well covered" in SO.

Comment: See also [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). It's from the "c++-faq" but still applies in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour.  The result could be anything.  This is because there is no [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the `++x` and the `x ^=`, so there is no guarantee which will be "done" first.

Comment: because what ? you mean x++ ,++x and so on...those order of calculation is not defined ,right?

Comment: @Andy, in particular, across the `^=`.

Comment: It's not true that there are no sequence points: the `||` operator is always a sequence point.  The only two modifications that cause UB are the last `++x` and the `x^=`.

Comment: @aschleper: Yes, you're correct.  My original answer was a little slap-dash; I'm going to clarify it now.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behaviour - so you can get any answer you'd like.

Comment: Well, any answer your compiler would like.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, this is undefined behavior. But why?

When programming in C, there is an inherent difference between a statement and an expression. Expression evaluation should give you the same observable results in any case (e.g., (x + 5) + 2 is the same as x + (5 + 2)). Statements, on the other hand, are used for sequencing of side-effects, that is to say, will generally result in, say, writing to some memory location.

Considering the above, expressions are safe to "nest" into statements, whereas nesting statements into expressions isn't. By "safe" I mean "no surprising results".

In your example, we have

```
x^=x || x++ || ++x;
```

Which order should the evaluation go about? Since || operates on expressions, it shouldn't matter whether we go (x || x++) || ++x or x || (x++ || ++x) or even ++x || (x || x++). However, since x++ and ++x are statements (even though C allows them to be used as expressions), we cannot proceed by algebraic reasoning. So, you will need to express the order of operations explicitly, by writing multiple statements.

Answer (score -1):

XOR 0 with 0 is 0. Then ++ twice is equal to 2. Nevertheless, as pointed in other answers, there's no sequence point. So the output could be anything.

Comment: xor 0 with 0 is actually _0_. `0,0->0, 0,1->1, 1,0->1, 1,1->0`. That's not a good start to an answer :-)