# Decrement operator and decrement assignment, different behaviour

Tags: c#, operators

Hello we are doing this programming exercise: [String doubles](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a145ab08ba9148dd6000094).

We would like to know with a detailed explanation (and more examples step by step if possible) why this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static class Kata
{
  public static string Doubles(string str)
  {  
    Console.WriteLine("str: "+str);
    for(int i=0; i<str.Length-1;i++){
      if(str[i]==str[i+1]){
        str=str.Remove(i--,2); //➖➖ operator does not store the modified i value inside i?
        Console.WriteLine("str: "+str);
      }
    }
    return str;
  }
}
```

Behaves differently than:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static class Kata
{
  public static string Doubles(string str)
  {  
    Console.WriteLine("str: "+str);
    for(int i=0; i<str.Length-1;i++){
      if(str[i]==str[i+1]){
        str=str.Remove(i,2); 
        Console.WriteLine("str: "+str);
        i-=1; //➖= operator DOES store the modified i value inside i?
      }
    }
    return str;
  }
}
```

We have read:

- [How do Prefix (++x) and Postfix (x++) operations work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812178/how-do-prefix-x-and-postfix-x-operations-work)
- [What is the difference between i++ and ++i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729)

EDIT: For example with the following string:

zpezyhgwqevkekipkxboraceiehzpvajbjalaymsgvqlepelorhjgznaqtaghusuiypywzthoxasudhterdcwzvgyflmcgbjgfwqvefgmimdnzfsrgcpdqewohehvqlphqyzjvwpnbmpthydaiszcgnealtybeydagjvkndocgibgmxmnadtyxcynidjsxluzxelamjmpaxlfkjvsghmslztxuvevfymnawxwrtmnqinksdiopjwedqlnfqfqjblyfnlzanvybclifrmqfwczavthkdnvimztxucqjirndaediodolnylxkueowazqcdzilusmuimstcgvyrtolwnaxbmirxawfuwulawaeclrabiabhworlvpgrqnamqprwxmzegtrljvzwtlgkametzgnuzrlwawbwbdwgbkelrutpfgoerdmtrmjhlryouvrxkjixpyrpcpqkmfhvnajhfptpvklwcwewyrptmxrpjurafthzirncdtdachdgmtgqhqgtompqfzyuerjrolicsenpqetgedhxupmqsocbmnoebhdlcusbldyrcksjmcrofsyzjgpeqjniahdjlgmqrkoblsjdblmbhogkveotmtetjkfcqlokxudwnqxmcewmbmatosohbxyvxrjyxzuamxrmgyfbhcrhwxjloyxhizwizvhyocjvzeuonpnmazfqyezmpwdfprpyzjtinoxasnculkgitgjvwvjdrnsupdzpqesrlrsymljulsygxioemyzkxkiyvjihroxcnlikloqebavjgqamrusbtiqlzdajiuvdvcmkihcoseiwpxifwapmaxzmalvxqohazilysuvhodnphzfmuhskhqohikfbohgmjyhvrsjwzozgprjwnaioavklbnoyxejvqheypzblrzhcuoaozrmonvjgqwhaqvwuacrokinpekdiqnvwyieribtjpedqjmgznpalerexkdrbpdbkchrflzzayilnbrcqzfwmelrnufdtobvanohrmeswmxbadvoqdesajsrlgtesvcdlyetpztoqpvbifxyrhnepxzstxcfwvsxjqdlcapdawkrwmeupgiezcuxfvmlszjkvhufenpladmhwhwabcgloeqbrfqpelilrugypcrxevpmbyzljqtxwtozskzbzkpcucmeurauledwueforkpzcmjpjwbtwqixrhdpdeqwhjvwaqfljovqzhswuxpgrmnwnykchkjgeaunvloldyvsyjogvfojyjrijdcgahgkgsdscgbesnusruyekehbwzivilerihkwslmvdodkrlpzrofyafogkhkrckwkcxafisxoasxliwfjtpmjlownxfvylmltngirymgnbhvcynxnymzobnhdwzdohexclhjyiespfvhiwkoyvbhuqkecrbdgzcewznpqdzeuvlhmwoctzwxacghgampdrkuyuwxmyecsgdzkgquhbfqpnwsxujwevlftzbnmzhvsxkzdhqfyidsekydzrpiyxvxfkfdhitjxrdwopedxwlcuqpizpgkznegcfavabpuvmhbojnclsweponyiecmspsinzdcvknhfijoupcvzxbljypmibskriurigwogafoyheyetbhnvogypkrutscqwosfotombgvzjxzvzdchgdqonicxbtmtqznuxemzdpcjkvhbcgmkvbdsdnupgzvoxuqderbhdrpjqaexqjncyvbuwfruptxseuyzcvjoxldugxixzwlspbtwhyzmsicvlywkzqhstkypqbyugrvsiedcacsdvojibyxiptzfgfaeganjngutkdnjghtpthtmdofxywvndvbzvbnhoaklwcruxylklygafybxvnbkafgshgmsclbsrdgezxctfspauwaqmazalrvzmrlsiaenzngxodhgaodhmqslztuahaihsimjlencbgqcavmvseqhwefvawalsygfpjxgqyabgfapldgyhckalodrioecjcaknrygfujuhvyzuxeuqdvoxjcypgrxrdepctfztnsptqpdwxdgxpmwoytodgejdfirseaclfvhtzcsdkzcribdaqwnjpmjmuirolotojliclulasjbdnderbintwtmuzrkdswgnhwsbovsjxotzlqvnjtmkbpopqrvmtwdnwqlgqdwhzmtyjwmrickxafqpgxwyufcgqguxthpeimpwojnhbeijtknhbcqkorunidcoxamfpnpuawkpxqwsmkajkmgnoxbabjfmghwnqsutgesbnxuydsdluzortzvajkjpwythprgbunkaedgmjvmwvzedzgjsrdoefcevcmesfehtzrtxbocadtcmrzscvhmzuxylkwqtqrsqpfhrzubaceyksqufadiozctinexikmblwlsbcbfmxpynstbktnispbfeyqgxctumjgtjnzaguoqkdfqtcmpwdjvufncmvijdvlelzsxumbxbkvbsanuqexialydawolmfnorbetjoukclumjlhntzxdepxplwxgjrwtkbjngoqotnmdeymnroxesurwlmaymrpndrqkwpjmwjlvlmprbqjmbtnrcpkunqvuxhshugyilqbnocnimnhdidbrjgyqhurpmicnwurlrzd

We see:

[image]

Comment: For what value of `str` do they behave differently?

Comment: Which .NET implementations (.NET Framework, .NET Core,...) do you use? In Framework 4 - 4.8 in runs smoothly and the output of both Functions with your given input is the same.

Comment: to show you my code i used: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Usxucs maybe you watch a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the value of i changes, but after we pass the current value to the Remove method, if we want to pass the new value to the Remove method, we put the decrement operator in front: 
`--i` or do it on a separate line:

```
 i--;
 str = str.Remove(i,2);
```