# Undefined/unspecified?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is `i = ++i + 1` unspecified behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860461/why-is-i-i-1-unspecified-behavior)

Consider the following snippet :

```
int i=10;
printf("%d %d %d",i,++i,i--);
```

The order in which the arguments to a function are evaluated is unspecified in C/C++.So it lead to unspecified behavior.

Am I correct or missing something ? Please Explain.

EDIT:Well,some member believes it to be duplicate and this is an Undefined behaviour.Anyways,from C99:

**6.5.2.2(10)**

The order of evaluation of the function designator, **the actual arguments**, and
subexpressions within the actual arguments is **unspecified**, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

So what would be the exact nomenclature now,**Undefined** or **Unspecified** ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860461/why-is-i-i-1-unspecified-behavior

Comment: And the term is undefined: It leads to "undefined" behavior. You could turn into a cat.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621542/compilers-and-argument-order-of-evaluation-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c

Comment: How that is duplicate of this ? :O

Comment: @GMan : Please explain, how this leads to undefined behaviour ?

Comment: Go to the duplicate question. The reason I'm linking you there is so we don't have to repeat information. :P

Comment: That said, Greg's duplicates are probably more relevant.

Comment: First, never do this. Second, maybe a typo, but you want to print three numbers and you only have two %d. It should be "%d%d%d".

Comment: It leads to undefined behaviour because the C and C++ Standards say it does.

Comment: @Jabba:Thanks,for pointing,it's a typo.

Comment: @Jabba, I also thought about it, but then there are more parameters than placeholders, not vice versa ;-)

Comment: @ Neil Butterworth : Do you mean order of evaluation of function argument is UB by C standard ? Can you please explain `6.5.2.2(10)` C99.

Comment: @GMan Your duplicate is not related at all, you should read the questions entirely. This is about the order of evaluation of parameters, where the other one is about operators priority. Fixed. (btw you've even answered "Go to the duplicate question" though you have not read the OP one :/)

Comment: @TheSamFrom1984: Exactly,I already mentioned it,but he retorts to sarcasm.I don't want to reinvent the wheel either but that link doesn't have my answer.

Comment: The order of evaluating arguments is unspecified, meaning the compiler has to evaluate all of them, but can arbitrarily order them.  However, there are no sequence points here.  You're modifying a variable more than once without an intervening sequence point, and that's undefined behavior regardless of the order of evaluation.

Comment: Thanks David I understood it now :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c  This is the more accurate possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, true.

I take it it's because on different platforms different machinery is employed to pass arguments and therefore parameters may be evaluated in different order.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is an example of where the C/C++ spec is undefined, so different compilers can do whatever they want.  One compiler might execute the parameters in left to right order, another might do it in right to left order.  It would be perfectly OK for a compiler to pick the order randomly.

The point that your source is trying to make is that you shouldn't rely on any order when passing parameters.  For example if you had:

```
A(DoX(), DoY())
```

DoX and DoY can't rely on any side-effects of the other, because they're executed in an undefined order.  To be perfectly explicit you'd want to do something like:

```
int x = DoX();
int y = DoY();
A(x, y);
```

For the majority of real-world production code you don't run into this situation very often, but it does happen every now and again.

Note that this is related to, but different from [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).