# Catch double free and handle it properly

Tags: c++, memory-management, crash

I faced some crash at `delete()`. I try to wrap `delete()` with try-catch and handle it properly but I still have crash instead of fall into catch section.

Here is example example of what I try to do.

```
int *i = new int();
delete (i);
try {
    delete (i);
}catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Oops";
}
```

The questions is "why I can't catch it in such way?" and "how I can properly catch situation like this?".

Comment: What compiler/OS do you use?

Comment: You might want to look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074727/a-pointer-that-can-point-to-anywhere-how-to-determine-if-delete-can-be-safely/43077127#43077127 here. The question is similar to yours.

Comment: Use std::unique_ptr!

Comment: In C++11 there's almost never a reason to call `new`, and absolutely, positively no reason whatsoever to call `delete`. You are trying to fix the symptoms that stem from using C++ in a way that was common almost two decades ago. We have since moved forward and access to better tools (e.g. `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delete operator does not throw exceptions:

> Exceptions (none)                 (until C++11)
>
> noexcept specification:  noexcept (since C++11)

cf [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

A double delete is a programming error. You should not try to handle it: use debugging tools to get rid of them (and better memory management with RAII and the standard class that use RAII)

Comment: Note that double deletion is Undefined Behavior. In other words, anything may happen, and "anything" includes a `noexcept` function throwing an exception ! Still, the conclusion is correct: don't handle it, prevent it. (+1)

Comment: a noexcept function throwing an exception will call std::terminate() (which by default call std::abort)

Comment: That's the specific rule, but the Undefined Behavior rule trumps every other rule.

Comment: I agree, but would delete throw an exception (which it shouldn't since delete specification say it shouldn't) std::terminate would be called (with post C++11 code). So there is no way (even if some UB would cause delete to throw an exception) that you could handle double delete with a catch. But in the end, I agree with you, once UB are out, the rest does not matter much.

Answer (score 2):

delete is a no exception operation, so you won't be able to catch it.

Answer (score -3):

Use a variable in the stack to store whether or not the variable was deleted. If you can't do that, then try using realloc instead of delete.

Comment: How do you plan to get rid of _that_ variable? You need a third variable to keep track of whether the second one is deleted. And then a fourth...

Comment: @MSalters I plan to use a stack variable, which will automatically get deleted when the program exits.

Comment: that would be a global variable. And the problem is, _which_ global variable would you use? A linked list of items might have thousands of nodes, all allocated with `new`, and you often won't know up front how many. Besides, if you did, why didn't you make that list a global?

Comment: Never ever use realloc in C++.

Comment: At some point, it become easier to create your own allocator where a double delete is a no-op.