# C++ code for right triangle using WHILE loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I need to print this triangle:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
```

using a FOR and WHILE loop. I need help, I have already figured out the for loop version I just have to convert it to while loop but everything I try is not giving me the correct output! Any help is appreciated!

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    int N = 8;

    while (i <= N)
    {
        i = i++;
        while(j <= i)
        {
            cout<<"*";
            j = j++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the triangle, i don't know if it showed up (right triangle)                                                                                                                            *                                                                                                                                          **                                                                                                                                        ***

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, add the homework tag.

Comment: you don't need `i = i++` and `j = j++`. just `i++` and `j++` will do the trick.

Comment: `j = j++` says "increment `j`, then assign `j` the value it had before incrementing it."  Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the rules?

```
while (1)
{
    cout << "*" << '\n';
    cout << "**" << '\n';
    cout << "***" << '\n';
    cout << "****" << '\n';
    cout << "*****" << '\n';
    cout << "******" << '\n';
    cout << "*******" << '\n';
    cout << "********" << '\n';

    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a hint (in the interest of making you do some figuring out yourself): You're forgetting to set `j` back to `1` after the inner loop.

As it is now, when `j` gets to be `<= i` once, it stays that way and the inner loop is never entered again.

---

Also, while it's not directly related to your question, make sure **never** to do `j = j++` or `i = i++`; just do `j++` and `i++` (as Kshitij Mehta said in the comments). If you're interested in why, you can [read this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914315/difference-between-i-i-and-i).

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint as well: `i = i++;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your triangle, but I think you need to set j to 1 before *each* loop on j:

```
while (i <= N)
{
    i++;
    j = 1;
    while(j <= i)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        j++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: When it's a homework question, try to encourage the OP to come up with the right answer by giving hints, and not the actual answer (like Seth did).

Comment: @kshitij OK, it make sense (the homework flag was added after but I could have guessed)

Comment: @teebee Glad it helped; don't forget to correct the `i=i++` statements like the others said (I copy/pasted your code without paying attention).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to make it more succinct than this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    int i = 10;
    while (i--)
        std::cout << (ss<<'*', ss).str() << std::endl;
}
```

or as for loop, cutting down a line

```
for(int i=10; i--;)
        std::cout << (ss<<'*', ss).str() << std::endl;
```

---

If you don't mind some less efficient code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { for(int i=1; i<10; std::cout << std::string(i++, '*') << std::endl); }
```

Comment: While that's a very concise solution, it is not very legible _especially_ for someone who's just learning C++.

Comment: Uhoh, I knew that :) But hey, it's like homework, and if I'm going to spoil the fun, I better make it interesting along the way. It worked for me that way :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>   

using namespace std;    

int main() 
{
    int i, j, N=7;  
    while(i <= N)
    {  
        i++;  
        j = 1;  
        while(j <= i)
        {
            cout << "*";  
            j++;
        }
        cout << endl;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Variable "i"  is not initialized.