# c++ what does "iter = ++iter" do? is it valid?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a question on c++ std iterators.

suppose `iter` is `std::set<SomeType>::iterator` type.

Is:

```
iter = ++iter
```

the same as:

```
++iter
```

or are they different?

---

edit:

I found a code    `std::set<UserDefinedClass*>::iterator`
 being used that way. (pointer)
I wonder if that can cause the program I'm debugging malfunction.
I'm reading up the answers but it's hard to judge which answer is correct.

Comment: I think this is UB as the program is ill formed

Comment: @iammilind: If you're worried about sequence points, remember that these are iterators, not primitive types.  So `++` is an operator overload, so there is a sequence point here; hence the behaviour is well-defined.

Comment: @iammilind: "Ill-formed" in C++ terminology designated a program that contains diagnosable errors, i.e. simply speaking a program that does not compile. UB on the other hand is usually a consequence of non-diagnosable errors. `iter = ++iter` in the above example is not ill-formed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no definitive answer to this question. The answer depends on the nature of `std::set<SomeType>::iterator` type. If it is a user-defined type (i.e. a class with overloaded operators), then the behavior of `iter = ++iter` is defined ans is indeed equivalent to a mere `++iter`. However, if `std::set<SomeType>::iterator` is a built-in type, then `iter = ++iter` produces undefined behavior, since it modifies the same object twice in one expression without an intervening sequence point (violation of the requirements presented in 5/4 of the language standard).

So, theoretically in general case one should avoid doing something like that since in general case the behavior is undefined. In practice though `std::set<SomeType>::iterator` will normally be a user-defined type and `iter = ++iter` will work. Nevertheless this is not a reason to use such expressions in the code.

Comment: Is it possible to have `std::set<X>::iterator` as a typedef for a builtin? My initial reaction is no as to make `*iter` work, then only type that would work would be an `X*` but the way that `++iter` and `--iter` would then work would imply that `set` would have to be implemented as an array, but then you couldn't erase an element from the middle of the `set` and maintain valid iterators to other elements. I may have missed something but I don't think that it's possible.

Comment: @AndreyT: *if `std::set<SomeType>::iterator` is a built-in type, then `iter = ++iter` produces undefined behavior* [`[citation strongly needed]`](http://xkcd.com/285/)

Comment: @Charles Bailey: I don't see how one can implement a compliant `std::set` with iterator being implementable through a built-in at the same time. This is why I said that in the real life it should "work". But in general case I woudn't discard the possibility.

Comment: @AndreyT: The edit is better, but I would still like to understand why assignment does not introduce a sequence point. How in the world could it be done in parallel with anything else? Aren't sequence points placed precisely to prevent parallel evaluations from happening?

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you thing that the assignment introduces as sequence pointer, *you* have to provide the reference. You can't site where a sequence point *isn't* specified.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't understand the "parallel" reference. Assignment does not introduce a sequence point because the standard doesn't say it introduces a sequence point. The fact that assignment changes its LHS is a *side-effect* of the assignment. The fact that `++` changes its argument is a *side-effect* of `++`. You have two competing side-effects in this case ("competing" = acting on the same object). The language does not care that these side-effects lead to the same end result. Every time you have multiple side-effects affecting the same object the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @AndreyT: +1 Yes, I now believe you're right. However, not arbitrarily: I believe there's a *reason* the standard doesn't say it requires a sequence point, and that it's due to parallelism -- I've updated my answer with a potential explanation of why this might be the case.

Comment: Note that `iter = ++iter` is well defined in C++11. (because of `§1.9/15 ... "The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator." ...`)

Comment: @Mankarse: Yeah... Sequencing is considerably revamped in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are the same thing - but why do this?

Comment: No the former is undefined. The same variable is modified twice within the same sequence point.

Comment: i'm debugging a code, the line looked suspicious and wanted to make sure if that's a valid code

Comment: @ereOn: What about the sequence point after the evaluation of the parameters for the function call `operator=`? Doesn't that separate the `++` from the `=` ?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Well, I might be wrong but I remember a question where the OP asked something quite similar and someone explained very well how this was undefined. I just can't get my hands on it. Perhaps it was about `i = i++` and not `i = ++i` (not sure if it changes something). Was that a rhetorical question or are you sure it works ?

Comment: @ereOn: Yes, it was probably `i++` and not `++i`.

Comment: @ereOn: I'm not 100% certain, but I can't think of any valid type that `std::set<X>::iterator` could be that wouldn't require `=` to be provided by an overloaded operator function. If it is a function then I'm fairly sure that I'm correct as any read or write performed by `++` would have to be separated from any read or write on the same object caused by `=` by at least one sequence point.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: It seems [you are right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914315/difference-between-i-i-and-i-closed). My bad. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. It's always good to learn.

Comment: @ereOn: Something tells me the answer you linked to might be wrong. Everywhere else on the 'net, the example they cite is `i = i++`, not `i = ++i`. But I could still be wrong, as I have not seen the standard itself.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I was more linking to the whole question, with all its answers and comments, not particularly to the most upvoted answer. Anyway, I haven't seen the standard either so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @Mehrdad: What do you believe is the fundamental difference between `i = i++` and `i = ++i`, w.r.t. UB? (Obviously, I'm not talking about the result if there is no UB which is different between the two expressions.) If `=` is a function call then there's a sequence point in both cases, if `=` is the built-in assignment operator then there's two writes with no intervening sequence point in both cases.

Comment: @Charles: Never mind, I'm convinced that you're correct. +1 for Ed.

Comment: @AlfPSteinbach: Was that -1 at the answer? If so, are you on the side of UB or did you have other reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same thing. A simpler case, same thing:

```
int i = 10;   //i = 10
int j = i++;  //j = 10
int k = ++i;  //k = 12
```

However

```
i = ++i;
```

is unnecessary as it increments i and then assigns i to i

Comment: It is not only unnecessary, it is *not allowed* for an int as it changes i's value twice without an intervening sequence point. The question likely uses overloaded operators (function calls) so the result there is different (and defined).

Comment: Not going to downvote, but I agree with @Alf. "Proof by example" doesn't work in the case of undefined behavior -- by definition, U.B. can include "reasonable" behavior.