# In C, is { a[i] = a[++i] } equivalent to { a[i] = a[i+1]; i++;}?

Tags: c, arrays, pre-increment, operator-precedence

In C, is

```
a[i] = a[++i];
```

equivalent to

```
a[i] = a[i+1]; i++;
```

That is, which side of the assignment is evaluated first and what value of `i` is used on the left side? Or is this assignment ambiguous?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Don't write such code.

Comment: @Amadan, actually, it is not. From http://stackoverflow.com/a/3914332/434551, "C++03 [Section 5/4] says Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. " Here, `i` is being modified only once.

Comment: @RSahu: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2989841/240443), a quote from K&R, with this exact example. The fact that it does not violate one constraint does not mean it can't violate another.

Comment: It is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/1009479), [the second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4177063/1009479) explained it explicitly.

Comment: @RSahu http://ideone.com/bzC8EQ

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I stand corrected :)

Comment: @Yu Hao: Thank you, that Q&A clearly resolves my question. The behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same sequence point you are using and incrementing `i`

```
a[i] = a[i++];
```

which will lead to undefined behavior.

```
a[i] = a[i+1];
i++;
```

is good.

And to answer your question *are they same* ? No they are not !! One if well defined and another is not.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989841/3883560)