# Why cout<<++i + ar[++i]; and cout<<ar[++i]+ ++i; give different output?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pre-increment

I have read about undefined behaviour.

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771786/6656729) says `a[i] = a[i++]` leads to undefined behaviour.

But I don't understand why the output of

```
int arr[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int i = 0;
cout << arr[++i] + ++i << " " << i;
```

is `3 2`

and the output of

```
int arr[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int i = 0;
cout << ++i + arr[++i] << " " << i;
```

is `4 2`

Comment: Have you also already read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior ?

Comment: `a[i] = a[i++]` is well-defined since C++17

Comment: in any case a C++ question should not be closed as duplicate of C question, since the sequencing rules are different'

Comment: I have read about UB. It should apply when you assign and increment at the same time. But here, there is no assignment. Instead the value of i is incremented and printed (not assigned) using cout.

Comment: "It should apply when you assign and increment at the same time." - not necessarily. Take a look at the 6th example of [undefined behavior in C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++): no assignment.

Comment: @enzo wikipedia is not a good reference, and none of the examples cover the code in this question anyway

Comment: @M.M That's why Wikipedia itself have [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#References). My comment was referring to the OP comment stating that undefined behavior only happens on assignment, which is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly - `a[i] = a[i++]` is well-defined since C++17. The sequencing rules were considerably tightened in that revision of the Standard, and the evalution of the right-hand side of an assignment operator is *sequenced before* the evaluation of the left hand side, meaning that all side-effects of the right-hand side must be complete before evaluation of the left-hand side begins.

So that code is equivalent to `a[i+1] = a[i];  ++i;`

---

Since C++17, the `<<` operator also has left-right sequencing, i.e. the left operand is *sequenced before* the right operand.

Now, `++i` is defined as `i+=1` and similar considerations as above apply to the evaluation of the compound assignment operator. The `++i` occurs "atomically" we could say.

However, the `+` operator is still *unsequenced*, this is defined by [intro.execution]/17:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are *unsequenced*.
>
> [...]
>
> If a side effect on a memory location is *unsequenced* relative to either another side effect on the same memory location or a value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location, and they are not
> potentially concurrent, the behavior is undefined

Unfortunately this means the behaviour of `++i + a[++i]` is still undefined, because the left operand of `+` modifies `i`, and the right operand of `+` modifies `i`, and those operand evaluations are unsequenced relative to each other.

---

It has previously been proposed to make `+` and similar operators be left-right sequenced as well, but apparently this hasn't been accepted into the Standard yet.