# C++ map lowerbound()

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I tried to use the lowerbound() in C++ STL Map. Before I use it, I test its functionality through a program like below:

```
int main ()
{
  std::map<int,int> mymap;
  std::map<int,int>::iterator itlow;

  mymap[1]=20;
  mymap[3]=60;
  mymap[4]=80;
  mymap[5]=100;

  itlow=mymap.lower_bound (2);  

    //Test1
    std::cout<<(--itlow)->first<<'\n';  //print 1
    std::cout<<itlow->second<<'\n';   //print 20

    //Test2
    std::cout<<(--itlow)->first<<": "<<itlow->second<<'\n';  //print 1 : 60        
}
```

I tested 1 and 2 separately which means when I tested 1, I commented Test2 and same as reverse. 
Test 1's result is under my expectation, but I don't understand why Test2 print 60 for the second field instead of 20?

Comment: Test 2 has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Could you please more specific? Thanks!

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior) for many such examples. There's also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points?rq=1).

Comment: The code doesnot build `print 1 : 60` is probably a comment.

Comment: Moreover Test1 use the first map element and Test2 unreferenced an invalid iterator. You got 1:60 but you can get others values...

Comment: I would like to know why you say Test2 unreferenced an invalid iterator?

Comment: You are reading and writing the same variable between sequence points and that's undefined behavior. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unspecified whether `(--itlow)->first` is evaluated before or after `itlow->second`. If it's evaluated before, you get `20`; otherwise, you get `60`.

See [order of evaluation of operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112282/order-of-evaluation-of-operands).

Comment: You can't read from and write to `itlow` "between sequence points".

Comment: @chris: So you're saying it's undefined rather than unspecified?

Comment: Well, I guess if [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690141/multiple-preincrement-operations-on-a-variable-in-cc/3691469#3691469) is to be believed, it is pre-C++11 and not after. It's always fun how things can subtly change.