# What is the output of following code (answer varies on diff. compilers)?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int j=0;

cout << ++j << j++ << j;

return 0;
}
```

To my knowledge, the output of the code must be 1 1 2 but the output of the code is 2 0 2, and this answer varies from compiler to compiler I am using the latest version of gcc. But when I use turbo c compiler the output is different.

So please explain the background working of the code.

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, and therefore can produce any outcome whatsoever. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194076/in-c11-does-i-i-1-exhibit-undefined-behavior

Comment: << is an overloaded operator., so ++j, j++, j end up being function arguments. The order of evaluation of function arguments is undefined.

Comment: Pretty much identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891791/postfix-and-prefix-operator-giving-unexpected-answer-in-cout-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: You can't modify `j` multiple times in the same statement like that - it's UB. Do this instead: `cout << ++j; cout << j++; cout << j;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << ++j << j++ << j;
```

Order of execution for '++j' and 'j++' here is not specified at all (both of them are function operator << () arguments). Compilers treat this as **undefined behavior**. On this line, anything could happen and no results are guaranteed. You can read about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).