# Does the placement of a pre-increment operator make a difference here?

Tags: c++, pre-increment, coverity

In the following C++ code is there a difference between the values of `x` and `y` at the end?

```
const int LoopLength = 100;
unsigned short x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < LoopLength; i++)
{
    x = ++x % 2;
    cout << x;
}

cout << endl;

unsigned short y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < LoopLength; i++)
{
    ++y = y % 2;
    cout << y;
}

cout << endl << (x == y) << endl;
```

Coverity (static-analysis tool) claims that the order in which the side-effects take place is undefined with a line like `x = ++x % 2;`. I'm unsure if I should worry about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005508/so-why-is-i-i-1-well-defined-in-c11

Comment: The `x` line is not bad, though you should put brackets around the bit you want to happen first, if the standard leaves the order undefined. The `y` assignment, however, looks like a disaster waiting to happen. Does that even compile?

Comment: @underscore_d The first line should be well defined due to the rule Stephen's linked answer.  The preincrement operator returns a glvalue which can be assigned to so it is perfectly fine syntax-wise to put it on the left hand side of the assignment operator.  I get the feeling that undefined sequencing around the operator will make the overall behavior undefined, though.

Comment: Thanks - I was just reading through explanations of why it can yield a valid lvalue and came back to edit my comment, but I was too late. Learn something new every day :) I think I personally would avoid it though, unless I was writing something for the IOCCC!

Comment: ++y = y % 2; may result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @underscore_d It compiles =/. I just talked to a coworker who shuddered after looking at the y line though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both forms are totally undefined prior to C++11 because they both write to the same memory location without an intervening sequence point.

According to the linked question [So why is i = ++i + 1 well-defined in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005508/so-why-is-i-i-1-well-defined-in-c11) the first form is legal in C++11, due to more restricted sequencing of writes.

I believe that the second case is not well defined as the order of evaluation of the operands to `=` are not specified.

Luckily all these questions can be avoided by *never ever* writing code that anywhere near resembles this. Your future code maintainers will thank you and send you gifts from the future.