# Error in the standards?

Tags: c++, standards

§5/4 C++ standard

```
i = 7, i++, i++;  // i becomes 9
i = ++i + 1;  //the behavior is unspecified
```

That should be changed to

```
i = 7, i++, i++;  // the behavior is undefined
i = ++i + 1;  //the behavior is undefined
```

right?

Comment: Why are you asking us and not the authors of the spec?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sequence point error: unspecified or undefined? ](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#351)

Comment: Since you're quoting the C++ standard, it's not really a C question so I removed the tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is `i = ++i + 1` unspecified behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860461/why-is-i-i-1-unspecified-behavior)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
i = 7, i++, i++; // i becomes 9
```

is perfectly fine. Operator `=` has higher precedence than `,`so the expression is equivalent to

```
(i = 7), i++, i++;
```

which is perfectly well defined behaviour because `,` is a sequence point.

As far as

```
i = ++i + 1; //the behavior is unspecified
```

is concerned the behaviour is [**undefined** in C++03](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#351) but [**well defined** in C++0x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#637). If you have the C++0x draft you can check out in section `1.9/15`

```
i = i++ + 1; // the behavior is undeﬁned
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, please see this defect report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#351 .

Clarification: the example is wrong but your 'fix' is incorrect for the first statement. The first statement is correctly commented in the standard. It is only the second comment that is inaccurate.

Comment: You should mention that this only affects the wording of “unspecified” vs. “undefined”, not the sequence point itself, which is fine.

Comment: @KonradRuddolph: Correct, I have clarified my answer.

Answer (score 4):

No, the standard is right. The [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) guarantees that any side effects of previous operands are completed before evaluating the next.

These guarantees are provided by [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), which the comma operator (as well as `&&` and `||`) are.

Note that you are correct on the wording change for the second statement. It is undefined, not unspecified.

Comment: The normative part of the standard is 'right' by definition, but the example is non-normative and has been acknowledged to have been wrong.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the 'unspecified' to 'undefined' change. Thanks.

Comment: Bizarrely, I don't think they're called sequence points in the C++ standard. They have the same concept (so it doesn't invalidate the answer) but I can't recall what they're called.

Comment: @paxdiablo : They are called [sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) and nothing else.

Comment: @Prasoon, you may want to look at the C++ standard. The phrase sequence point appears in there exactly zero times.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's not in the new standard because the term is being deprecated, but I believe it's in the '03 standard (sorry, I don't have a copy on me to check).

Comment: @paxdiablo : Check out section 1.9/7 (C++03).

Comment: I stand corrected. Serve me right for looking at the wrong version of the standard :-)

Answer (score 2):

> That should be changed to
>
> ```
> i = 7, i++, i++;  // the behavior is undefined
> ```

Why? The standard is correct, this shouldn’t be changed, and this behaviour is well-defined.

A comma (`,`) introduces a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) into the calculation so the order of execution is defined.